# Qfield layers are not where they should be. CRS problem?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing, geolocation, qfield

I have created a basic QGIS project with a basemap and a point layer saved with CRS OSGB 1936/British national grid.  When uploaded to Qfield, my actual location and the layers I have uploaded don't match.  I presume this is a beginners CRS problem?

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly. Check under Project Properties, and then layer properties for each layer. If your base map is, for instance Google, in Project_Properties_Transformations you also need to have appropriate translations loaded.

[image: Project_Properties_Transformations]

The Transformations are added by pressing the green plus button. This opens the dialog below. Select your source CRS, which for Google is EPSG:3857. And your destination CRS, i.e. the CRS you use, for instance BNG (or more accurately, EPSG:27700).

[image: Slect Datum Transformations]

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar issue. When you say 'you also need to have appropriate translations loaded', how do you go about including them your qfield project ? Could you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: see updated answer